# Can I enforce linear layout for the reference types with Array/List?

Tags: c#, memory-management, collections, reference

Say I have reference type (`class`) objects and I would like to store them in List or Array. Can I force those collections to store the actual data (not references) in the linear manner?

If not, is there any low level container that is capable of doing this?

Comment: You may want to have a look at serialization.

Comment: @TaW, you think about deserializing entire collection?

Comment: It is a way to flatten the data to retrievable text. Yes, why not the whole collection. Other than that, I don't know how to do it short of writing generic code for you class. The objects will not work until you deserialize them, that's right..

Comment: @Taw, sure I can get text, but this makes objects not-operational.

Comment: What __exactly__ do you want to achieve?

Comment: If you want to control memory layout, C# is the wrong language. Also, when this collection collides with other code, it would have to (in some way depending on how exactly it works) either break the memory layout promise or the usual rules for reference types. There are also issues with subtyping and probably a dozen other things. It's just not how the language works. **Why** do you want this?

Comment: @delnan, errm, to put data (data, not just references) in such way, that after reading object `n` the incoming data would contain data of object `n+1`. This could lead to some performance optimization, because linear access of memory is faster than random.

Comment: @greenoldman Ah, so you're only after good cache use. In that case, forget it. It's not worth doing the impossible. Use structs and arrays when it makes sense, but don't try turning the object model 180° and don't try to turn reference types into something they aren't.

Comment: @delnan, I am not asking if it worth it or not, but how to do it (assuming it is possible).

Comment: To a degree, I respect that. On the other hand, when someone asks you in all seriousness how to subway surf from A to B, you tell them that it's dangerous and pointless and they could just ride *in* the subway. SO is not only for answering your questions but also for making you [ask the right questions](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377). I can't force you, obviously, but my professional opinion is that this approach simply isn't feasible (either impossible or marginal benefits overshadowed by immense problems), and that you should look at other ways of improving performance and cache use.

Comment: @delnan, I am not asking because I intend to use this, but because I am curious of the limits of C# when it comes to hard core performance optimization (for comparison: in C++ it comes with the language, because the allocation is by usage, not by definition). Another story is that writing testimony to every second question is really tiresome (I prefer being ignored than flooded with why's).